# XSLT code to convert one xml to another xml

Tags: xslt

Hi Guyz I am new to XSLT. Please help to create the XSLT to get the below output.

input XML

```
<ProjectedMonthlyIncomeList>
  <ProjectedMonthlyIncome>
      <StartDate>2014-09-11T00:00:00-04:00</StartDate>
      <EndDate>2014-09-30T00:00:00-04:00</EndDate>
      <Month>Sep</Month>
      <Income>372.00</Income>
  </ProjectedMonthlyIncome>
  <ProjectedMonthlyIncome>
      <StartDate>2014-10-01T00:00:00-04:00</StartDate>
      <EndDate>2014-10-31T00:00:00-04:00</EndDate>
      <Month>Oct</Month>
      <Income>222.00</Income>
  </ProjectedMonthlyIncome>
  <ProjectedMonthlyIncome>
      <StartDate>2014-11-01T00:00:00-04:00</StartDate>
      <EndDate>2014-11-29T23:00:00-05:00</EndDate>
      <Month>Nov</Month>
      <Income>379.00</Income>
  </ProjectedMonthlyIncome>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates match = "ProjectedMonthlyIncomeList/ProjectedMonthlyIncome">
        <xsl:with-param name="sequence" select="1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ProjectedMonthlyIncomeList/ProjectedMonthlyIncome">
    <xsl:param name="sequence" />
        <xsl:if test = "$sequence = '1'">
            <mon1><xsl:value-of select="Income"/></mon1>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML

```
<Mon1>372.00</Mon1>
<Mon2>222.00</Mon2>
<Mon3>379.00</Mon3>
```

I want Income tag to be mapped to Mon1, Mon2, Mon3 from each ProjectedMonthlyIncome tag

Comment: Post your XSLT, what you have tried.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
   
   <xsl:apply-templates match =                                             "ProjectedMonthlyIncomeList/ProjectedMonthlyIncome">
   <xsl:with-param name="sequence" select="1" />

   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ProjectedMonthlyIncomeList/ProjectedMonthlyIncome">
<xsl:param name="sequence" />  
<xsl:if test = "$sequence = '1'">
<mon1><xsl:value-of select="Income"/></mon1>
</xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Now how can i increment the value of sequence

Comment: Usual Practice post your INPUT xml, XSLT code, required RESULT in code area, not in comment area. See my code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="ProjectedMonthlyIncomeList">
    <xsl:for-each select="ProjectedMonthlyIncome/Income">
        <xsl:element name="Mon{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. We are using version 1.0 so dont know if the code snippet will work

Comment: I am assuming it will work in ver 1.0 also, just change the XSLT version to 1.0.

Comment: How can we do the same thing if the tag names are different like say instead of mon1, mon2 we have monstart, monend and so on

Comment: Only two types? 'monstart' and 'monend'?, in such cases use if condition, like if position="1" then 'monstart', if postion="2" then 'monend'.

Comment: no not only two types if we have say strings as tags then we cannot use position function so in that case what should be the aproach

Comment: @GaneshNaykodi, post new question with requirement, that is convenient to answer.

Comment: Okay will do that. Thanks.